# Android UI Kit - lookamore

Tags: android

I downloaded [lookamore](http://arttolstykh.com/v1.0/lookamore/), **Android UI Kit**. I found a `.psd` file (Layer Photoshop) but I don't know how to use these files in Android development.
Can someone give me a sample code?

Or is it possible to use **psd** files directly in Android?

Comment: You have to export the Photoshop to JPG / PNG images suitable for your layout ( and use it via codes ). Try first !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sample code and Android has no native method to open PSD files.

You can convert these to another format, such as JPEG, GIF or PNG (depending upon the bit depth of your PSD files and how you are planning on using them) using either an online converter or using a graphics program.

Here is an article giving some programs to try, I recommend GIMP:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-best-ways-to-open-a-psd-file-without-photoshop/

Answer (score 0):

Extension with `.psd` file is not supported by android that we can use directly in our application for that to extract the images from `.psd` as per your requirement i.e. for different sizes.

Try this [link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121006004121AAkTdin) this might give you complete idea about this.